# How to convert a 'states' object class list to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am working with the opensky network api: https://opensky-network.org/apidoc/python.html

I am calling the api via the python library they've created and am looking to turn the object returned into a dataframe. Below is a snippet of what it looks like, how would i go about turning this into a dataframe?

```
from opensky_api import OpenSkyApi
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
api = OpenSkyApi()
states = api.get_states()

for s in states.states[0:2]:
    print("(%r, %r, %r, %r)" % (
        s.longitude,
        s.latitude,
        s.baro_altitude,
        s.velocity
        )
        )
```

Here is the structure of the states object:

```
    {   'states': [
        StateVector(dict_values(['a2e5ec', 'SKW3594 ', 'United States', 1585323288, 1585323288, -116.2179, 43.567, None, True, 3.09, 292.5, None, None, None, '1130', False, 0])),
        StateVector(dict_values(['a57b1e', 'N452SD  ', 'United States', 1585323339, 1585323339, -88.496, 37.7587, 12192, False, 188.65, 218.24, 0, None, 12519.66, '6263', False, 0]))
    ],'time': 1585323340}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at how it is done by the traffic library: https://github.com/xoolive/traffic

https://github.com/xoolive/traffic/blob/c3cafc4298536538a6c8e73c6ec1bde1c8050021/traffic/data/adsb/opensky.py

Answer (score 2):

based off user160531's advice, using the traffic library:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from traffic.data import opensky
from traffic.drawing import EuroPP, countries
sv = opensky.api_states()
df = sv.data.head
print(df)
```